# Matrix homeserver (Synapse) setup for mautrix-whatsapp

Tags: networking, vpn, vps, whatsapp

I would like to install a Matrix homesever on a VPS (running Debian 10) for the sole purpose of using the WhatsApp bridge, `mautrix-whatsapp`. I really only need to be able to communicate with my personal WhatsApp using a Matrix client, so there's no need to use federation or anything like that (AFAICT). Since this use is a bit different from common homeserver setups, I was hoping someone could elucidate a few things for me.

1. The VPS in question mostly serves as an OpenVPN server. I would like to have the Matrix homeserver only accessible from clients connected to the VPN. To the OpenVPN clients, the server is accessible by IP at 192.168.xxx.1. Clients connect to the VPN by IP; there is no *externally* accessible FQDN associated with it. Is this going to be a problem? N.B. the VPN clients typically use the DNS server (Pi-hole) running on the VPS, which does allow them to reach the server by its hostname. Can I just use this hostname as the domain namee for Synapse and mautrix-whatsapp?
2. Port 443 is NOT available, because I redirect it to 1194 so clients can connect to the VPN on restrictive public networks. Although [the documentation](https://www.natrius.eu/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=digital:server:matrixsynapse) says "a reverse proxy should be reachable publicly with a regular certificate (e.g. Let's Encrypt) on port 443 that goes to the port 8008 of synapse", I'm assuming things will work out just fine if I use a different port and point the Matrix client (Element) to it. Is that correct?
3. In fact, since the client connections will already be encrypted by virtue of OpenVPN, could I forgo the reverse proxy entirely? If so, is that sensible, and is there anything I need to know w.r.t. configuration, etc?
4. In this configuration, do either Synapse or mautrix-whatsapp require me to open ports to the outside world (i.e. outside of the VPN's 192.168.xxx.0/24)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I decided to just take a leap of faith and try, and it worked! The answers:

1. I just used `localhost` as the domain name, which works fine.
2. Element-desktop works just fine if you point it to the server, in my case 192.168.xxx.1:8008.
3. The reverse proxy is not needed. Using plain http works fine out of the box. Still about uncertain whether it's the most sensible thing to do, but it's the simplest.
4. No external ports are needed. I've force-closed TCP 8443 as an extra precaution, but that should not actually be necessary. Synapse needs to listen on 0.0.0.0, but mautrix-whatsapp can be told to listen only on 127.0.0.1.